# How to find source of .backpack.dropzone in all Chrome web pages

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I am learning HTML/CSS/JS, and am perplexed by a CSS stylesheet that gets loaded into the Chrome browser when I look at the Inspector View. This does not appear in other browsers.

Specifically, it is a style element that appears in the head section.  It starts off as:

```
.backpack.dropzone {
    font-family:....
```

...and it goes on for about 60 lines.

Is there a way to determine why this style element gets added to every one of my web pages in Chrome?  Is there a way to remove it and prevent its loading?

Thanks

Comment: this can possibly be added by a chrome extension you are using

Answer (score 0):

This gets added by the Skype Chrome extension.